# Not apply jQuery LazyLoad plugin recognizing if the client is a bot - cakephp

Tags: jquery, cakephp, seo, bots, lazy-loading

I would like to implement LazyLoad Jquery plugin to increase the speed of loading pages of a site but do not want to compromise the image indexing in search engines.
I found some solutions, such as the use of tag  but I don't think they are the best solution.

This is thought to check (server side) if the user agent client is a crawler or a "regular" visitor to apply the LazyLoad Plugin or not.

For this I would like to know if this is a good idea and would like to get some help on how to deal with CakePHP2.2 to check if a bot since there are many.

Comment: This would be best done on the server side with the user agent. Many bots do not read javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should always use the `alt` attribute with an image, otherwise it would fail to validate.

For SEO, one way of going about this, is to make sure you have a fallback to the normal version of the image when JavaScript is disabled, which would be indexed by Google.

So, using the `<noscript>` tag, you could achieve this.

Example :

```
<img src="loading.jpg" data-image="path_to_image" alt="Description of Image" />
```

would become :

```
<noscript>    
    <img src="path_to_image" alt="Description of Image" />
</noscript>
```

**Update** :

There is an alternate method to make sure that your images do get indexed,  by using [**Image sitemaps**](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=178636).

Comment: But seems that google don't index the content of noscript tag and is for this that I'm looking for other solutions

Comment: Google does not index `<noscript>` because the crawlers have JS engines.